# UISplitViewController - rightBarButtonItem on the primary view controller does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an IpadCoordinator defined as:

```
class IpadLayoutCoordinator: BaseCoordinator {

    private let rootViewController: UINavigationController

    private lazy var splitVC: UISplitViewController = {
        let vc = UISplitViewController(style: .doubleColumn)
        vc.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth = 450.0
        vc.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 450.0
        return vc
    }()

    init(navController: UINavigationController) {
        self.rootViewController = navController
    }

    override func start() {
        let primaryViewCoordinator = PrimaryViewCoordinator(rootView: splitVC)
        primaryViewCoordinator.start()
        self.parentCoordinator?.store(coordinator: primaryViewCoordinator)

        let secondaryView = UIViewController()
        secondaryView.view.backgroundColor = .blueColor           
        splitVC.setViewController(secondaryView, for: .secondary)
    
        let containerVC = UIViewController()
        containerVC.addChildViewController(splitVC, toView: containerVC.view)
        rootViewController.setViewControllers([containerVC], animated: true)
    }

}
```

My primary view controller is set through the PrimaryViewCoordinator as follows:

```
class PrimaryViewCoordinator: BaseCoordinator {
    
    private let rootViewController: UISplitViewController
    
    private lazy var primaryVC: PrimaryViewController = {
        let vc = PrimaryViewController.loadFromNib()
    
        /* This is the button not working */
        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(self.goToAddVC))
        vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    
        return vc
    }()

    init(rootView: UISplitViewController) {
        self.rootViewController = rootView
    }

    override func start() {
        rootViewController.setViewController(primaryVC, for: .primary)
    }

    @objc private func goToAddVC() {
        /* This is the action not working */
        let addItemCoordinator = AddItemCoordinator(rootView: rootViewController)
        addItemCoordinator.start()
        self.store(coordinator: addItemCoordinator)
    }

}
```

The `AddItemCoordinator` just presents the `AddItemViewController` over the entire view. The problem is that the code inside of the `@objc selector` never executes. The action never executes. I can edit the bar button type and visuals but the action will not execute.

If I add a `rightBarButtonItem` the same way for the secondary view controller, it works just fine. It's only the primary view controller that has this issue.

I even tried adding the `rightBarButtonItem` in the `start()` function in case it was losing its reference to `self` but that didn't work either.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this bug?

Comment: Add a `deinit`to your `PrimaryViewCoordinator`. Is it being called sooner than expected?

Comment: Oh wow yeah it was! Storing the coordinators before calling the start() functions fixed the issue. Thank you so much! This issue has been killing me for a week now.